# Exporting an Fbxscene with Fbx SDK 2020 but it's empty

Tags: c++

here using fbx sdk i created a scene to export and then added nodes to the root node
however no nodes are added to the root children after export

```
    void FbxSceneData::Export(FbxSceneData^ scene, System::String^ path)
    {
        FbxManager* fbxManager = FbxManager::Create();

        FbxIOSettings* ios = FbxIOSettings::Create(fbxManager, IOSROOT);
        fbxManager->SetIOSettings(ios);
        FbxExporter* Exporter = FbxExporter::Create(fbxManager, "");

        const char* pathPtr = StringToConstChar(path);

        // Set the FbxIOSettings EXP_FBX_EMBEDDED property to true.
        (*(fbxManager->GetIOSettings())).SetBoolProp(EXP_FBX_EMBEDDED, true);

        // Get the appropriate file format for FBX 2020 binary.
        int lFileFormat = fbxManager->GetIOPluginRegistry()->FindWriterIDByDescription("FBX binary (*.fbx)");

        // Initialize the exporter with the specified file format
        Exporter->Initialize(pathPtr, lFileFormat, fbxManager->GetIOSettings());

        FbxScene* fbxscene = FbxScene::Create(fbxManager, "");
        FbxNode* rootNode = fbxscene->GetRootNode();

       // ... Prepare the fbxscene data for export ...
        FbxNode* fbxNode = FbxNode::Create(fbxscene, "child1");
        FbxNull* fbnull = FbxNull::Create(fbxscene, "child1");
        fbxNode->SetNodeAttribute(fbnull);
        rootNode->AddChild(fbxNode);
       
        
        




        // Export the scene
        Exporter->Export(fbxscene); 
        Exporter->Destroy();
        ios->Destroy();
        fbxManager->Destroy();
    }
```

```
const char* StringToConstChar(System::String^ str)
    
   }

        // Convert the System::String^ to char*
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(str);
        const size_t convertedSize = wcstombs(nullptr, wch, 0);
        std::string stdStr(convertedSize, 0);
        wcstombs(&stdStr[0], wch, convertedSize + 1);

        // Return the const char* from the std::string
        return stdStr.c_str();
    }
```

The resulting fbx file dosn't cuase any proplems when importing it to blender it's just empty
in the decumentation i did not find any more steps after

```
AddChild()
```

Comment: You never use the `scene` parameter passed into that function. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes .the FbxSceneData is where i store my scene objects . hence this is part of c++ wrapper the main app in c# , there should be code to convert to FbxScene but i faild to add nodes , so for simplicity i only tried to create and add a new node but the resulting scene only contains the root node when opening it with the scene treeviewer